# How to build a Typescript type from an array of strings?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So far I have this.

```js
export const PacerThemes = ['Default', 'Dark Muted', 'Neon'] as const;
export type PacerTheme = typeof PacerThemes[number];

type ThemeProperties = {
  exhaleHoldBorderColor: string;
  exhaleHoldColor: string;
  inhaleHoldBorderColor: string;
  inhaleHoldColor: string;
};

type Themes = {
  Default: ThemeProperties;
  'Dark Muted': ThemeProperties;
  Neon: ThemeProperties;
};
```

Is there a way to generate the `Themes` type from the `PacerThemes` array?

Comment: `type Themes = { [ThemeName in PacerTheme]: ThemeProperties; };` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types

Comment: @GarlefWegart [it doesn't work?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wAoEMHCgFQAtgBbYVOAXjgG0ByAEWADMsBXAGxjoBo5GsUANZwAsmxjAAJr34A5YCjoBdOFgpI0MANwAoUJFhwYATzDA42XAWJkqxs4uaWceIqXI1kbEgCM8ynq6puZw7mQYUBDmsACW5PYA3rpwcKCEWBzAABIQHFIAQtBSeADCedAAXHDoULHIAOZ6qemZOXlS5RxVNTB1jc1w9RlZuflFUCVQXT219U0pQ8gj7fkzUNVzA7oAvkEhFuEJ1Ilwi6k0R3JYdvUu1kfK1UeR0Xgw8ajaZ3tAA)

Comment: @GarlefWegart [`typeof PacerNames[number]` also seems to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wAoEMHCgFQAtgBbYVOAXjgG0ByAEWADMsBXAGxjoBo5GsUANZwAsmxjAAJr34A5YCjoBdOFgpI0MANwAoXTACeYYHCKlgGKBBOwAluSpwA3rrhxQhLB2AAJCBxSAELQUngAwgHQAFxw6FB2yADmeu6e3n4BUpEcMXEwCcmpcIlePv6BIVBhUDl58YkpbiXIZZmBdVCxDUW6AL56Bsam5mQU1M5wze40o8ByWGQtcEYmEMxw2LgExGM0yGwkAEZ4ysqxc1Y2eDAOqNpTA7pAA). I'm really not sure which thing you reference as not working.

Comment: @VLAZ --- re: "it doesn't work". oh right. my mistake. I thought you made a typo and meant to write `PacerTheme_s_` (using `PacerThemes` as an index is what's not working). [I deleted my comment so that there's no misinformation floating around.] What you suggested is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgQ2AUwE4BUAWyC2yIwC8MA2gOQAiyAZggK4A2UZANDJQqgNYwCydUZABNW7AHLJwZALowEBUJCgAoVVACeAB2QwsuZHFQhtqKAEt8ANTQQz4IjADeymKR5mwMABQbtIavBIaHp4EACUJFzI6v4wvpIBiCgY2KEwAGQwYHQ4AEZo0tIAXDAARACaIHQYWsilygC+QA)):

```
const PacerThemes = ['Default', 'Dark Muted', 'Neon'] as const


type ThemePropertiesVersion = {
  [k in (typeof PacerThemes)[keyof typeof PacerThemes & number]]: "YourType"
}
```

---

If you wand to make this more generic by introducing some reusable helper types, you might encounter the problem that `readonly any[]` does not extend `any[]`.

For example, this would not work, since `typeof PacerThemes` is `readonly`:

```
type Items<A extends any[]> = A[keyof A & number]
```

To handle this you could to something like this ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgQ2AUwE4BUAWyC2yIwC8MA2gOQAiyAZggK4A2UZANDJQqgNYwCydUZABNW7AHLJwZALowEBUJCgAoVQHo1MAGpoIAS3AwAjDAC0MVPiio9wWAAMAkoJwR7MKCAvIEQ8AwBPOVRUBACIAG4YMBAAdxg9MFAcAAcEKD0AIwZkGFi9KEwYFIYERODQ8NUoAJTcgCUfPzBA51wIAB44GGQAD0EwIQJLX38ghDAAkmkAPiJ4Ei5kAJBqeBgAMmi6HEy0aWra3PQrHVR9cBNiMXBG6Bs7PQA3ZDbXDpq61fgkNCxcfAzQ51GD-PBwVAgOqoDL4M4XMBXGAAb2UMFIPHKjVGLQCb06n0ka0QKAw2DwEBm0gAXDAAEQATRAdAwRzpygAvqplBptLoDGAYAAmMzmBAMBhxGCZECFYG5G5gO7WWwZF74ro9frIQYEAAUI2agTkk2mAEoYAAfE1TWbzOCLZbfbpbMA7PaoA7KQmg0788Ai663KwPNWvFwEo7O35kgGU%20Wg8nICFQtCwiDwgWBlFojEJQWK5Wh57h9ofKPEmNgwE0%20lMlnoNmc5RAA)):

```
const PacerThemes = ['Default', 'Dark Muted', 'Neon'] as const


// Version 1 -- allow only readonly arrays

type ReadonlyItems<P extends readonly any[]> = P[keyof P & number]

type TestVersion1 = NonRestrictiveItems<typeof PacerThemes>

type ThemePropertiesVersion1 = {
  [k in ReadonlyItems<typeof PacerThemes>]: "YourType"
}


// Version 2 -- allow both

type NonRestrictiveItems<P extends (readonly any[]) | any[]> = P[keyof P & number]

type TestVersion2 = NonRestrictiveItems<typeof PacerThemes>

type ThemePropertiesVersion2 = {
  [k in NonRestrictiveItems<typeof PacerThemes>]: "YourType"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Garlef. This exactly answered the question. 

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), as suggested in the comments.

```
    type ThemeNames = "Default" | "Dark Muted" | "Neon";

    type ThemeProperties = {
      exhaleHoldBorderColor: string;
      exhaleHoldColor: string;
      inhaleHoldBorderColor: string;
      inhaleHoldColor: string;
    };

    type Themes = {
      [T in ThemeNames]: ThemeProperties;
    };
```

---

Or you could use a [Record utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)

```
    type ThemeNames = "Default" | "Dark Muted" | "Neon";

    type ThemeProperties = {
      exhaleHoldBorderColor: string;
      exhaleHoldColor: string;
      inhaleHoldBorderColor: string;
      inhaleHoldColor: string;
    }

    type Themes = Record<ThemeNames, ThemeProperties>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AVAFjAtjAcgQzQZ2AXmACIARGAM0wFcAbMI4AH2JMwCcBrYAWSrBgAmDZkXQwA9gDsiAbgCwAKEWhw0OElQwACm3Gw2YAJYw8hAN7KVwGAA9EmGjAAS4mgIBC4tgJhsAwq5eAFzAOGBshpIA5vIKVtZ2Ds6uAgE0waHhkTGWKpH2ji5unt6%20aRlhEdGx8flJRamBbCGV2TWgAL6KuaqwCMi4BMAASjAAxl4CADwaaFi4ADT9mjp6vkYmAHzdSnGgE5JhwCgQsyYhZ6bAFnvxZJS0YCE38fG2BcnFk2VNIQDkrWifwWPVeCQ%20DXKzWAAKyQJBtzBwDqhRSJR8-l%20MMBUWBoNeKM%20jXS0NhVVxS3xIA6CLBpHYXF4-CEzypVne9TR30xJP%20OLxiLBHNRbihfLhFLZeUkEK5pR5GTJ2QFSNAhMhWKV8OAbJpbLEUlZgtewqJ6J%20vOxEpVqvBnNFmv5tNt6rlGLFVvJNtVrodlq1FJ1xupzupOwA8gAjABW4zAADoODAIDgABQnS4ASnjKEwUFTYAGMAA0smCJtgAccK4YPH0lEC0XSxBM5nFEA)

Comment: Yes. Mapped types are the correct thing to do. However you can solve this without explicitly defining the `ThemeNames` type. See my answer.

Comment: @kasv Thanks for the answer. I like this but it doesn't exactly answer the question. The reason I use an array to define the theme names is to map it into a menu `PacerThemes.map((pacerTheme: PacerTheme) =>`.

Comment: True. However, with this approach you could always use the resulting data structure to map over -  `Object.keys(myThemes).map(key => {...})`